# How to go from one activty to another fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have an Activity called Mytaskonclick extends Activity and a Fragment called SentTaskFragment extends Fragment. I want to go from Mytaskonclick to SentTaskFragment on click of a button. I tried using the code

```
Intent ii=new Intent(Mytaskonclick.this,SentTaskFragment.class);
startActivity(ii);
```

But this code doesn't work. Can anyone suggest me how to do it?

Comment: fragment is modular part of activity so you can replace or add fregment in you app not switch like activity.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments does not work like this.You need to put a place holder in your activity, say FrameLayout for example and, inside on click, you get the fragment and attach it inside this placeholder.  I suggest you read the [Fragment Tutorial Here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html). It contains all what you need to know and extremely useful for you.

Comment: So is it not possible to go from an activity to a fragment?

Comment: No. Fragments can not be shown by its own, it must be included in an Activity. You can make another activity, put the fragment inside it and open that activity using the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to switch to a `Fragment` them you have to do that through `FragmentManager`. Pass that thae `Fragment` object into `beginTransaction()` method of `FragmentManager` along with the container layout which will hold the `Fragment` as below...

```
SentTaskFragment fragment = new SentTaskFragment();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

You can see some tutorial from below link...

[Android Developer-Fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html)

[Multi-pane development in Android with Fragments - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)

[Android Fragments](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm)

[Android Fragments Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/)